# EF 6.1 how to swap migration configurations for testing?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use Integration testing using EF 6.1 and run into a problem that my migration configuration settings are used where I dont need them. And I cant figure out how to swap them out for testing.
Here is my Test Class:

```
[TestClass]
public class SXSeasonConverterTests
{
    public void RecreateDatabaseForTesting()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new TestDatabaseSeedingInitializer());
        using (var context = new BaseNFLContext("NFLContextIntegrationTests"))
        {
            context.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
    }

    public SXSeasonConverterTests()
    {
        RecreateDatabaseForTesting();
    }
}
```

Here is my Initializer class:

```
public class TestDatabaseSeedingInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BaseNFLContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(BaseNFLContext context)
    {
        //Add Teams
        context.Teams.Add(new Team { Code = "ARZ", Name = "Arizona Cardinals" });
        context.Teams.Add(new Team { Code = "ATL", Name = "Atlanta Falcons" });
        ...
    }
}
```

However when I try to run the test, I get the error that my AutomaticMigrations are disabled. When I looked further I found that It uses this code on Initialize:

```
internal sealed class NFLConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BaseNFLContext>
{
    public NFLConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }
}
```

This code is obviously there for production. However when doing testing how can I swap those migration configurations and set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`?

Answer (score 0):

I used to test my EF stuff using a special unittesting database and executed the tests in a TransactionScope which was rolled back at the end of the test. This way, no data was actually stored in the database.

I wasn't fast, but it suited our purpose.

Comment: Thank you, but I am more interested in the DropCreateDatabaseAlways scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate project for testing and have a separate Db context that points to a test database. You can create something like a `IDbContext` interface that tells you which object models need to be tested. Also, the data access layer needs to allow you to inject this test Db context as a dependency.

Comment: What you are suggesting is Faking, isn't it? However whats the point of faking in integration tests? I understand that when you are doing integration testing all you have to do is use a test database in your test classes isn't it?

Comment: Oh no, your test Db context will connect to a test database not a fake. The data layer you use in prod will use the test database to run the tests.